# How terraform know which resource should it run first to spin up infrastructure?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I’m using terraform to spin up Aws-DMS. To spin up DMS, we need subnet groups, dms replication task, dms endpoints, dms replication instance. I’ve configured everything using terraform documentation. My question is how will terraform know which task to be completed first to spin up other dependency tasks?
Do we need to declare it somewhere in terraform  or is terraform intelligent enough to run accordingly?

Comment: https://learn.hashicorp.com/terraform/getting-started/dependencies.html

Answer (score 3):

Terraform uses references in the configuration to infer ordering.

Consider the following example:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "example" {
  bucket = "terraform-dependencies-example"
  acl    = "private"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "example" {
  bucket  = aws_s3_bucket.example.bucket # reference to aws_s3_bucket.example
  key     = "example"
  content = "example"
}
```

In the above example, the `aws_s3_bucket_object.example` resource contains an expression that refers to `aws_s3_bucket.example.bucket`, and so Terraform can infer that `aws_s3_bucket.example` must be created before `aws_s3_bucket_object.example`.

---

These implicit dependencies created by references are the primary way to create ordering in Terraform. In some rare circumstances we need to represent dependencies that cannot be inferred by expressions, and so for those exceptional circumstances only we can add additional explicit dependencies using the `depends_on` meta argument.

One situation where that can occur is AWS IAM policies, where the graph created naturally by references will tend to have the following shape:

[image: both aws_lambda_function and aws_iam_role_policy depend only on aws_iam_role]

Due to AWS IAM's data model, we must first create a role and then assign a policy to it as a separate step, but the objects assuming that role (in this case, an AWS Lambda function just for example) only take a reference to the role itself, not to the policy. With the dependencies created implicitly by references then, the Lambda function could potentially be created before its role has the access it needs, causing errors if the function tries to take any actions before the policy is assigned.

To address this, we can use `depends_on` in the `aws_lambda_function` resource block to force that extra dependency and thus create the correct execution order:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "example" {
  # ...
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "example" {
  # ...
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "exmaple" {
  depends_on = [aws_iam_role_policy.example]
}
```

[image: Now the aws_lambda_function also depends on the aws_iam_role_policy]

---

For more information on resource dependencies in Terraform, see [Resource Dependencies](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#resource-dependencies) in the Terraform documentation.

Comment: Great explanation Martin.. really appreciate your response. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Terraform will automatically create the resources in an order that all dependencies can be fulfilled.

E.g.: If you set a security group id in your DMS definition as `"${aws_security_group.my_sg.id}"`, Terraform recognizes this dependency and created the security group prior to the DMS resource.